# Execute javascript function after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I have a javascript function that shows the register form after the onclick but it doesn't refresh because it is on the same page. It just loads another form in. But when I have the Reset Password page and I want a button that goes **directly** to the register form instead of the standard login form and that you have to click manually on the register button.

How can I fix that after the click on the a href the page refreshes and that it will use the javascript code so it will show the register form instead of the login form.

```
$('.register-pass-reset').click(function(){
    // Switches the forms
    ('.form').animate({
        height: "toggle",
        'padding-top': 'toggle',
        'padding-bottom': 'toggle',
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, "slow");
    $('.help-block').remove();
    $('.toggle').html($('.toggle').html() == 'Register' ? 'Login' : 'Register');
});
```

The a href:

```
<a class="register-pass-reset" href="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

Comment: you want to show the register form instead of login form(default form) when redirected to this page by reset password button in another page.

Comment: @M.Tanzil Yes like this gyazo: https://gyazo.com/86919845ac4bea1e5ef8061613df184f Here you can see how it looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to link to `url('/login#register')`, then detect the hash in the JS when the page loads:

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash == "#register") {
        //Change Login To Register Form
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[For detail about Web Storage Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**

You should use `HTML WEB STORAGE` to keep track of page. Like if `reset_password` button is pressed then `store a key with yourself in storage`.

Then in the other page `access that key and show the register form on the basis of its value` and then reset the key to null in storage for future usage.

**Here is how to use HTML web storage**.

When `reset_password` button is pressed add the below code in its click event.

```
localStorage.setItem("register", "true");
// where register is the key and its value is true
```

In another page access this `key` in its DOM ready function **like**

```
$(function(){
   if(localStorage.getItem("register") === "true") {
      // show your register form and reset the storage.
      localStorage.setItem("register","");
   } else { 

   }
});
```

Comment: [HTML Web Storage](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#storage) has known issues in IE8 up to IE 11.  Why would you recommend it to be used?